# Assign float values to NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, floating-point, nsmutablearray

I want to assign float variables to nsmutable array in a for loop. I did it like below. But the nsmutable array is seems null. How can I solve this? (distance is float and enyakinarray is  NSMutablearray.)

```
for (int i=0; i<[ws3.CustomerID count]; i++) {

    //radian hesaplaması
    float total = [first floatValue];
    float theta = total * M_PI/180;
    float total2 = [second floatValue];
    float theta2 = total2 * M_PI/180;
    float total3 = [[ws3.Latitude objectAtIndex: i]  floatValue];
    float theta3 = total3 * M_PI/180;
    float total4 = [[ws3.Longitude objectAtIndex: i] floatValue];
    float theta4 = total4 * M_PI/180;


     distance = 6371 * acos(cos(theta) * cos(theta3)
                           * cos(theta4 - theta2)
                           + sin(theta) * sin( theta3)) ;

    NSLog(@"xxxxx %f",distance);

    num = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:distance];
    enyakinarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [enyakinarray  addObject:num];
    NSLog(@"asasasas %@",enyakinarray);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the array is null (nil) then maybe you haven't initialised it?

```
enyakinarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Don't forget if you alloc it, you need to release it when finished with it.

```
[enyakinarray release];
```

Comment: Ok when I allocate the enyakinarray, it change every time. assign process is in the for loop. I want to do this: repeat the loop until another array count and distance calculated and add distance to enyakinarray.

Comment: I want to keep every distances which calculated in for loop in enyakinarray.

Comment: I'm happy to help, but need to see the code you've written so far. Edit your original question to put the updated code beneath your current code. - I will see what I can see with that.

Comment: ok I edited my question. The code is above :) thnx for your help

Answer (score 5):

**Adding a number to an array**
`NSArray (NSMutableArray)` doesnt allow you to add primitive types to it. This is because an NSArray is simple a set of pointers to the Objects you add to it. This means if you want to add a number to the array, you first have to wrap it in a `NSNumber`.

```
NSArray *numbers=[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:2]];
```

**Number type conversion**

NSNumber allows you to easily convert the type of a number e.g. from an int to a float

```
NSNumber *number=[NSNumber numberWithInteger:2];
float floatValue = [number floatValue];
```

Answer (score 3):

You are creating a new array every iteration of the for loop. You want to do this:

```
NSMutableArray *enyakinarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i<[ws3.CustomerID count]; i++) {

    //radian hesaplaması
    float total = [first floatValue];
    float theta = total * M_PI/180;
    float total2 = [second floatValue];
    float theta2 = total2 * M_PI/180;
    float total3 = [[ws3.Latitude objectAtIndex: i]  floatValue];
    float theta3 = total3 * M_PI/180;
    float total4 = [[ws3.Longitude objectAtIndex: i] floatValue];
    float theta4 = total4 * M_PI/180;


     distance = 6371 * acos(cos(theta) * cos(theta3)
                           * cos(theta4 - theta2)
                           + sin(theta) * sin( theta3)) ;

    NSLog(@"xxxxx %f",distance);

    num = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:distance];
    [enyakinarray  addObject:num];

}
NSLog(@"asasasas %@",enyakinarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CGFloat instead, I know that works. Also, I was reminded of something because of the comment below mine. NSNumber will work too, here is the class reference http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it, I rarely have ever used NSNumber. I always use CGFLoat

Comment: I'll add another answer that solves your problem and tells you what is wrong

Comment: You can't put `CGFloat`s into an `NSArray`; they are primitives, and `NSArray` can only hold objects.

Comment: Which is why i posted another answer